# Qt4 Wrapper results in Segmentation fault(s)

Tags: c++, c, qt4, wrapper

I'm currently writing a set of wrapper functions of Qt4 for an application as plugin (because I personally think that writing extensions in plain C is easier to accomplish).

At first I though this could be done by simply abstracting the following:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication* app = new QApplication(argc, argv);
    QPushButton* hello = new QPushButton("Hello world!");
    hello->resize(500, 300);
    hello->show();
    return app->exec();
}
```

Into this (as a matter of fact, that's the code in main.c of my wrapper):

```
#include "bind.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    gui_application_t* app;
    gui_pushbutton_t* hello;
    app = gui_application_new(argc, argv);
    hello = gui_pushbutton_new("Hello World");
    gui_pushbutton_resize(hello, 100, 30);
    gui_pushbutton_show(hello);
    return gui_application_exec(app);
}
```

While the former works (as expected), I'm getting segmentation faults at apparently random places in the latter. I hoped my version would just do the same as the former... but I'm afraid it doesn't at all :-(

After running the binary, the output is usually:

```
 *** GUI Debug: gui_application_new: ctx->app = hex_addr
 *** GUI Debug: gui_pushbutton_new: ctx->button = hex_addr
 *** GUI Debug: gui_pushbutton_resize: ctx->button = hex_addr
 *** GUI Debug: gui_pushbutton_show: ctx->button = hex_addr
Segmentation fault
```

However, even after removing the calls to `gui_pushbutton_*` (and only calling `gui_application_new` and `gui_application_exec`), the application will still crash, but in `gui_application_exec`.

Output from running the binary with gdb: http://codepad.org/wBifH1B2

Sources: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/863332/wrapper.tar.bz2

Any help is very appreciated, as this got me very puzzled...

Comment: You should not call this "bind". That is already both the name of a very popular DNS server application as well as a BSD sockets function name.  You should also try to include enough source here to make this at all debug-able.

Comment: @natgoose I'm not sure what you mean, "bind" is only the name of the directory I've used here. Also, the archive includes _all_ sources I've written. unless you also want me to include the full Qt4 Source Distribution... :-)

Comment: I've edited the question with the renamed headerfile.

Comment: @nebukadnezzar: I meant that downloading and extracting a tarball is a lot to ask for from strangers debugging your work.

Comment: @nategoose: You are right, I removed the sources for your convenience.

Comment: I meant that you should have tried to include more of it in your question.  The problem with it that I saw was not in code you have posted on here.

Comment: can't you run this in gdb? or look at the backtrace in the generated coredump?

Comment: @Idan K: added link with GDB output... but there is no coredump.

Comment: I have to say that I don't seem to understand what you're trying to accomplish with all this wrapping. It will be a nightmare just to wrap every Qt function you might need. If you need a C library, use GTK. Anyhow, please show the wrappers code aswell, the error is most likely there.

Comment: What Library i'm using isn't exactly open for discussion, and I do not plan to wrap every single Qt Class and function. I have added the sources again.

Answer (score 0):

A call to gui_allocate:

```
ctx = gui_allocate<gui_pushbutton_t>(sizeof(gui_pushbutton_t*));
```

suggests that the function works like `malloc` and takes a requested size and returns an address to a buffer of that size, but that is not the case.  This is a template-ed function, and each version of it knows the type.  It is really more like `calloc` than malloc because the call:

```
ctx = gui_allocate<gui_pushbutton_t>(1);
```

would allocate enough space for one `gui_pushbutton_t`.  `gui_allocate`'s parameter is an array length, not an element size.

You were allocating an array of them with length `sizeof(gui_pushbutton_t *)`.

I don't really see how that would cause segmentation faults since it should result in a larger memory than needed being allocated, unless it is either the constructor or some other action on behalf of these excess array members that is causing your problem.

Comment: the segmentation fault does not occur in the call to gui_allocate -- however, gui_allocate in general is a bad habit of mine. I could also just have written `gui_pushbutton_t* ctx = new gui_pushbutton_t;` which would do exactly the same thing... in a more sane way.

Comment: The segfault happens in `strlen` (__strlen_sse2) called by `int XSetCommand(Display *d, Window w, char * argv, int argc)`. Try writing `size_t __strlen_sse2(const char *s) { size_t z = 0; while(*(s+z)) {z++} return z;}` in your `main.c` and set a break point in  there and see what that is being passed.  You may have to play around with the name (using regular `strlen` or `__strlen`) to get it to use your version.

Comment: @nategoose I'm not sure what you mean, there are no strlen calls in any of the sourcefiles.

Comment: @nebukadnezzar: The gdb output you gave said that it was in a strlen call when the failure occurred. This call was made within a library function (not directly by your code). In fact, it was about 6 or 7 calls deep in library code. By replacing strlen with a version in your source I was hoping that it would be easier for you to see what it was passed in gdb when it failed, maybe yielding a clue.

Comment: @nategoose: I see. However, even though I managed to eradicate the segmentation fault by using a different approach, I still see no GUI, so I decided to use a different Library (most likely FLTK).